# Ukrsotsbank internetbanking applet error "Aplication Blocked by Security Settings"

Tags: java, security, ubuntu, applet

Here is link with [applet page](https://ibank.ukrsotsbank.com/internet-banking_ru.html). About my enviroment:

- I have Ubuntu 13.10 and chromium-browser as web browser.
- I have installed oracle jvm:

  ```
  $ java -version
  java version "1.7.0_51"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
  ```
- My ip_local_port_range

  ```
  $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range 
  32768   61000
  ```
- ibank.ukrsotsbank.com is already added to my exception list in jcontrol

When applet running it fall down with `SecurityException` with description `Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: https://ibank.ukrsotsbank.com/client2019UA.jar`

When I'm trying to start test page I havae `Application Blocked` error with description `Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running`

My security settings level is medium.

By the way, when I'm trying to open this applets from Windows 8.1 everything is OK and when I have asked my friend open it in his Gentoo - everything was OK.

If you take a look at clent.xml you'll see `port="433"` but when I change it using `$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="433 61000"` there is no effect.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your bank needs to include the permissions manifest in their applet (as the error message states). Did you try to decrease your security level? This may also work for you...

Comment: `My security settings level is medium.` I have lovest possible security level.

Comment: Then try to add the website url https://ibank.ukrsotsbank.com to the exception list: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/exception_site_list.html (you find the list in the Security tab of the Java Control Panel)

Comment: Already done. Error does not disappear.

Comment: Then as written in my first comment your bank has to add the permissions attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Missing required Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: 
   https://ibank.ukrsotsbank.com/client2019UA.jar
```

Well, the content of the manifest is (many `Name:` & `SHA1-Digest` entries deleted for brevity..

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 16.3-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Name: com/bifit/security/core/l.class
SHA1-Digest: d2WlbgJlgMWvzj4b5EjxPrd1IlA=

Name: com/bifit/util/VerbalNumber_ua.class
SHA1-Digest: YZt7ca1OqSFbsVlrjH9+4acukFg=

...

Name: com/bifit/security/token/CrystalNativeLoader$F2.class
SHA1-Digest: Fgczu0EVPvoSv5QKOqDSgIawfC0=
```

So the `Permissions` attribute is a) required and b) missing.  It should appear something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: MyApplet
Implementation-Version: applet build
Application-Name: Slide Show
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Library: true
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Trusted-Only: true
Permissions: all-permissions  // <- ensure this bit is in the manifest!

Name: com/bifit/security/core/l.class
SHA1-Digest: d2WlbgJlgMWvzj4b5EjxPrd1IlA=

Name: com/bifit/util/VerbalNumber_ua.class
SHA1-Digest: YZt7ca1OqSFbsVlrjH9+4acukFg=

...

Name: com/bifit/security/token/CrystalNativeLoader$F2.class
SHA1-Digest: Fgczu0EVPvoSv5QKOqDSgIawfC0=
```

Ensure the line marked `// <- ensure this bit is in the manifest` is in the manifest, but the comment is only there to show how it should appear.  Don't include the comment itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answer, I'll send link with this topic to their support with hope of changes ASAP.

Comment: Why it works on Windows?  Lower version of Java?  These changes were only introduced recently.

Comment: Do you mean update 51? What update doesn't contains last security updates?

Comment: I think they *started* to make changes around update 45.  Update 51 is the last update of those increasing security restrictions.